# Differences between methods of reporting variance

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, inference, mean, histogram

I am a neuroscience researcher without too much background in statistical theory.

I have multi recordings from different samples and I want to precisely report the variation across the samples, and I wanted to understand the differences between methods of doing this:

1. (arithmetic) Average of variances of the different samples
2. (arithmetic) Average of standard deviation of the different samples
3. (arithmetic) Average of SEM of the different samples
4. The variance of the average histograms of the different samples
5. The standard deviation of the average histograms of the different samples
6. The SEM of the average histograms of the different samples

The average histogram would be found by summing the percentage histograms of each samples in each histogram bin and then dividing the sample size.

I have a rough idea of the differences in each method, but not sure how to frame them in terms of statistical/probability theory. Thank you for your help as always!

Answer (score 0):

First the obvious part. Variance and standard deviation are basically the same, the variance is simply the square of the standard deviation. I always prefer to use the standard deviation because it is easier to interpret, since it has the same units as your data.

The SEM (standard error of the mean) is the standard deviation of the sample mean. This just measures what is the expected error in your estimation of the mean of the population, since you don't have an infinite number of examples and you are using your sample to estimate the mean of the whole population.

You can of course, apply these measures for the same bin of several histograms...

The main question that you should answer is: What do you really want to show? Once you know this the choice should be obvious.

For example, if you want to show that all samples are very consistent/inconsistent, you could simply calculate the average sample standard deviation as well as the standard deviation of the samples' standard deviations. This could allow you to conclude something like, all samples have a very similar standard deviation of X, or, for instance, that all samples have in average a low standard deviation, but the sample standard deviation changes a lot between samples...

From your question I am not sure, but maybe an ANOVA analysis can be interesting for your case. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance
There's a nice episode of the Data Skeptic podcast explaining it in very simple terms: https://dataskeptic.com/blog/episodes/2016/anova

Comment: Thank you for the answer; I am literally just trying to see the average. Then I will compare the average to a average of recording under different condition in each sample.

Comment: Also, arithmetic average of the std is different from the arithmetic mean variance (e.g. take std =3,4,5 avg var= 16; var = 9 16 25; avg std = 16.67); Is there a probabilistic interpretation of these differences?

Comment: "Then I will compare the average to a average of recording under different condition in each sample." then maybe what you need to do is a paired t-test. You calculate the standard deviation for each group for conditions 1 and 2. One pair will correspond to the 2 std. deviation values obtained for the 2 different conditions for the same group. You can calculate this with R or even with Excel. This way you will answer your question, whether the different measurement conditions have a significant impact on the standard deviation of the samples.

Comment: Regarding your example, I don't know exactly what you mean with probabilistic interpretation. The variance is the square of the std dev BUT the mean variance of different samples is NOT the square of the mean standard deviation over those samples.